# LSTM For Predicting Vector Sequences

Tags: keras, lstm, predictive-modeling

I am attempting to construct a Keras model that intakes a sequence of vectors and outputs the most likely next vector in the sequence. I have followed a few tutorials, but nothing is quite seeming to work. My accuracy is always extremely low, sometimes even 0, and loss increases.

My model is as follows.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))  
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))  
model.add(layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))  
model.add(layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"))  
model.add(layers.Activation("softmax"))  
model.build((None, 641, 300))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is this proper usage of LSTM? The code runs fine, no errors, but the model simply doesn't train.

Comment: Many unusual things in your model: why so many LSTM layers? why a ReLU and then a softmax? Why a softmax at all? Are the vectors probability distributions? Why using dropout if your model does not work properly yet?

Comment: @noe To be honest, I'm not sure, my model architecture was taken from a tutorial that seems rather old. This is what the tutorial advised. Would you advise a single LSTM layer instead of multiple? Should relu and softmax not be used together? The vectors are text embeddings.

Comment: Then there are many many wrong things in that code. I'd suggest following a different tutorial altogether.

Comment: @noe Probably good advice, but do you have any recommendations for improving the model in its current state? It's the only tutorial I can find on this topic.

Comment: Sorry, that code has more wrong things than correct things. Some amendments for that code: start with a single LSTM, as input use the token indices and have an initial embedding layer, as output activation use softmax but without ReLU, use a categorical cross-entropy loss. Or better, check other examples, like [this one](https://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/keras/rnn_language_model_basic_keras.html) for instance.

Comment: @noe That's a good tutorial, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I added the information above as an answer so that you can accept it and the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: If you find the answers to your question useful, please consider upvoting them. Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with that code:

- It uses a lot of LSTM layers. Instead, start with a single LSTM.
- As you are working with text:

  - Use token indices as input and have an initial embedding layer
  - Use softmax (but without ReLU) as final activation.
  - Use token indices as expected output.
  - Use a categorical cross-entropy loss instead of MSE.

I suggest you use another tutorial. For instance, [this notebook](https://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/keras/rnn_language_model_basic_keras.html) has the kind of setup that I was describing:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(num_classes, embedding_size, input_length = maxlen))
model1.add(LSTM(lstm_size))
model1.add(Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
model1.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
```